# how to access items of another category

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-k2

I need to change mod_k2_content template to output articles from one category: add few (2 for example) articles to this output in different places (3rd and 5th place of a list).

I can connect striaght to DB and grab articles from category to array and then mix it with default category output. but i am searching how to do this using k2 functions? does anybody has complete answer or any ideas where to search? thank you!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking for. would it be possible to see a small diagram, along with the code you're already using?

Comment: I'm sorry for bad explanation. i want to add advertisement article(s) to the newsfeed in certain order (for example: there are 7 articles in newsfeed on frontpage and ad article will be 4th all the time till its "Expires time" then it will be unshown). For now I modified mod_k2_content.php added this http://jsfiddle.net/BFQUP/ and in new module template did like this http://jsfiddle.net/uK72d/  All this far away from my needs but i am working on it. i will be very grateful for any help or advice. http://yadi.sk/d/Lx7dHiMq33Y69    http://yadi.sk/d/hty7oyjh33Y9d - how it looks for now

Comment: if you notice article #4 (from top) is the same all time on the screenshots